# Como diagramas software NO orientado a objetos?

Tags: funciones, diagrama-de-flujo

He desarrollado un pequeño sistema en Python, pero no he definido clases. Simplemente son archivos con funciones que se llaman unas a otras y un archivo `Main.py` central.

Me encuentro ahora tratando de representar este sistema, pero no encuentro el diagrama indicado para explicar el funcionamiento del sistema. Claro, he hecho casos de uso, pero quisiera representar las responsabilidades de cada función y como son invocadas cada una. Las colaboraciones entre ellas.

¿Con qué modelo puedo representrarlo? ¿Existen tipos de diagramas pre definidos para este tipo de sistemas?

Answer (score 1):

No sé si te he entendido bien pero, si utilizas casos de uso posiblemente estés usando UML.

En este caso, si lo que quieres es simplemente crear el diagrama de flujo puedes hacerlo utilizando [diagramas de comunicación](http://agilemodeling.com/style/collaborationDiagram.htm) o [diagramas de secuencia](http://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/sequenceDiagram.htm).

Estos tipos de diagramas normalmente hacen referencia a clases pero si no tienes clases si no módulos o funciones, también los puedes utilizar. Simplemente cambia la forma en que lo organizas.

Si quieres diagramas de flujo más sencillos puedes probar con metodologías de flujograma como Jackson, Warnier o Bertini.